# How to reposition div on decrease in screen size with css?

Tags: css

I have been trying to build a website having a 3 column layout. All of the body is given a margin:0 auto to keep it at the centre, and has a minimum width of 1218px.

Now, what I want to do is reposition the right column in such a way the it goes below the left column without affecting the centre column. A live example would be twitter home page, where at the left I can see my profile and trends, the centre column features the tweets and the right column shows suggestions on a 1366x768 screen, now if I change the screen size to 1024x768, the column of suggestions at right goes down below the left column but the central timeline is unaffected.

The definition would be:

```
<div class="containter" style="margin:0px auto;">
    <div class="left-col" style="width:290px; float:left;">Left Stuff goes here </div>
    <div class="center-col" style="width:590px; float:right;"> Center body </div>
    <div class="right-col" style="width:290px; float:right;">right Stuff goes here </div>
</div>
```

Now note that the central column has a right float, copied from twitter.

I can't use media queries for that since the website is going to deal with a lot of old browsers and also I would like to avoid JavaScript if possible.
Any help?

Comment: old browser... how much old? IE6?

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude I have tried the above code, to no avail. Is asking how to do something off-topic for SO?

Comment: @fcalderan old enough to not support Media Queries.

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee when I comment that the code was not showing.

Comment: I am using SO from mobile, so the code wasn't working correctly due to some reason, I had to edit it again, maybe that was the reason. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with "min-width" of the main container. You must use "max-width" since you want to make sure something happens when the screen width gets more narrow. And the main column (in the center) has to be left-floated, not right. Here's a possible solution. However the whole questions seems weird to me since you want to make a responsive layout in an old browser that doesn't support responsive CSS.

```
<style>
    .container {
        max-width: 1218px;
    }

    .leftColumn {
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: brown;
    }

    .mainColumn {
        float: left;
        width: 700px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: darkgreen;
    }

    .suggestions {
        float: left;
        width: 218px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: darkorange;
    }

    .cleaner {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="leftColumn">
        LEFT
    </div>

    <div class="mainColumn">
        MAIN
    </div>

    <div class="suggestions">
        SUGGESTIONS
    </div>

    <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the height of the main column isn't specified since the main column of mine can be really long, the right column doesn't start if the main column doesn't end. @Jan P.